# how to read the first 3 bytes in byte array

Tags: c#

I have byte array and I need to read only the first 3 bytes not more.

C# 4.0

Comment: This is a homework, isn't it?

Answer (score 23):

Any of these enough?

```
IEnumerable<byte> firstThree = myArray.Take(3);
byte[] firstThreeAsArray = myArray.Take(3).ToArray();
List<byte> firstThreeAsList = myArray.Take(3).ToList();
byte[] firstThreeAsArraySlice = myArray[..3];
```

Answer (score 9):

How about:

```
Byte byte1 = bytesInput[0];
Byte byte2 = bytesInput[1];
Byte byte3 = bytesInput[2];
```

Or in an array:

```
Byte[] threeBytes = new Byte[] { bytesInput[0], bytesInput[1], bytesInput[2] };
```

Or:

```
Byte[] threeBytes = new Byte[3];
Array.Copy(bytesInput, threeBytes, 0, 3); 
     // not sure on the overload but its similar to this
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple for loop can also do the job.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{
   // your logic
}
```

Or just use index in array.

```
byte first = byteArr[0];
byte second = byteArr[1];
byte third = byteArr[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
byte b1 = bytearray[0];
byte b2 = bytearray[1];
byte b3 = bytearray[2];
```

An array is indexed from 0, so the first 3 bytes are in the 0, 1 and 2 slots in your array.